cloudflare worker locally not starting problem while starting with cloudflare
PS D:\web\javascript\backend\hc\New folder\my-app> npm run dev

> my-app@0.0.0 dev
> wrangler dev


 ⛅️ wrangler 3.65.0
-------------------

⎔ Starting local server...
╭─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ 
[b] open a browser, [d] open Devtools, [l] turn off local mode, [c] clear console, [x] to exit                                   
│
╰─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

D:\web\javascript\backend\hc\New folder\my-app\node_modules\wrangler\wrangler-dist\cli.js:29765
            throw a;
            ^

MiniflareCoreError [ERR_RUNTIME_FAILURE]: The Workers runtime failed to start. There is likely additional logging output above.     
    at #assembleAndUpdateConfig (D:\web\javascript\backend\hc\New folder\my-app\node_modules\miniflare\dist\src\index.js:9178:13)   
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Mutex.runWith (D:\web\javascript\backend\hc\New folder\my-app\node_modules\miniflare\dist\src\index.js:3521:16) {      
  code: 'ERR_RUNTIME_FAILURE',
  cause: undefined
}

Node.js v18.20.4
PS D:\web\javascript\backend\hc\New folder\my-app> 

i try hono also no help
